# Multiply the dimensions and reset on action

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I do have an html which contains many elements with different dimensions which are positioned absolutely. I want to animate all of them, and change the width and height relative to the current one, like animate to a dimension half of width and height. Right now, animate do have `+=` and `-=` for relative increment or decrement.

(a) But I need to animate to half dimension, so is there any option like `*=0.5`?

And later, after animation, on clicking on a reset button, I need to reset the dimension. So I stored the base width and height in data attributes. But again `$(this)` won't work inside `.animate()`

(b) Please check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/9s4w7/), which is not working. Is there any work around for this?

I know using `.each()` it can be attained, but I don't want another loop as I got many elements in my markup.

Please check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/9s4w7/1/), which is a working version of what I want, but its using `.each()`. As I said above, I don't want another loop for this as the html contain lots of these elements.

(c) So is there anyway this can be attained without using `each()` and also I need to have reset functionality (removing style attribute won't work as these elements are positioned using inline style attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use step function: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/9s4w7/2/)

However I think you gain no real benefit from doing things that way.

Changes in your code I made:

```
shrink_ratio = 0.5;
$('button#trigger').click(function(){
    $('.object').animate({
        end: 1
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            startWidth = $(this).data('width');
            startHeight = $(this).data('height');
            $(this).css({width: startWidth - shrink_ratio * startWidth * now, 
                         height: startHeight - shrink_ratio * startHeight * now});
        },
        queue: false
    });
});

$('button#reset').click(function(){
    $('.object').animate({
        end: 0
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            startWidth = $(this).data('width');
            startHeight = $(this).data('height');
            $(this).css({width: startWidth - shrink_ratio * startWidth * now, 
                         height: startHeight - shrink_ratio * startHeight * now});
        },
        queue: false
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked.. Thanks... :-) Also it contains about 250 elements and by doing this way there is good performance increase when comparing to `.each()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it without .each(). You can make the animation run without going through a queue, if you are worried about delays. 
And also, I'd add a stop(true, false) to your reset function (and/or vice-versa) depending on how you like the animation to respond to simultaneous clicks.